# rails3 rspec issue

Tags: rspec, bundler, rspec2

I am trying out rails3. I am using [**railstutorial**](http://railstutorial.org/)
site to explore more about rails3; the tutorial is very good to begin with (I have minimal experience with rails2).

I have an issue with rspec which is currently blocking my progress. I saw that the tutorial recommended using rspec2.0.0.beta.18 gem; I instead installed rspec2.0.0.beta.20 gem using

```
bundle install
```

However I find issues with this version of rspec
My rspec for integration_test looks like:

```
describe "LayoutLinks" do
  it "should have a About page at '/about'" do  
    get '/about'
    response.should have_selector('h1', :content => "About Us")
  end 
end
```

The failure looks like:

```
Failures:
  1) LayoutLinks should have a About page at '/about'
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     stack level too deep
     # /home/arun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185
```

(NOTE: Those who have looked at [**Chapter 5**](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top) will not have issues understanding the context.)

If I change rspec version to 2.0.0.beta.18 in the Gemfile and run rspec I get the following error

```
arun@ubuntu-world:~/Project/Rails/rails3/sample_app$ rspec spec/
/home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.0.0.beta.20, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.0.0.beta.18. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup'
        from /home/arun/Project/Rails/rails3/sample_app/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /home/arun/Project/Rails/rails3/sample_app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /home/arun/Project/Rails/rails3/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /home/arun/Project/Rails/rails3/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /home/arun/Project/Rails/rails3/sample_app/spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:302:in `load'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:302:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:302:in `map'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:302:in `load_spec_files'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run_in_process'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `run'
        from /home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.20/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem. At [the end of Chapter 5](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout), tests from **/spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb** are all failing with the same error (the controller tests work just fine):

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace 
stack level too deep
# C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185
```

After doing a little troubleshooting on the **/spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb** file, it appears that using `response` within this context is what triggers the problem. For example, there is no error if the file reads as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do

    it "should run tests properly from this file" do
        get '/'
    end
end
```

But the file as copied from the tutorial reads:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do

  it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
    get '/'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
  end

  it "should have a Contact page at '/contact'" do
    get '/contact'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
  end

  it "should have an About page at '/about'" do
    get '/about'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
  end

  it "should have a Help page at '/help'" do
    get '/help'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
  end
end
```

The error is thrown as soon as `response` is called

This is on Windows 7 (I've attempted to setup Ruby, Git, Vim, and other development tools at the system level rather than within Cygwin).

Rspeicher - following RailsTutorial.org's steps, the **/config/routes.rb** file looks something like this:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
 get "users/new"

 match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'

 match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
 match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
 match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'

 root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

like Arun says, this all works as intended in the browser, so the issue seems to be somewhere within rspec or ruby. I suppose this isn't a problem if ruby is installed under Cygwin. I was hoping to not have to revert to a pure Cygwin environment, especially since my webroot and project files are already managed outside of Cygwin's virtual unix folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

The second error should be fixed by re-running `bundle install` whenever you change your Gemfile.

As for the first error, could you post the lines from your routes.rb file where you define the '/about' route?

Answer (score 0):

I ran "bundle install" again and when I look at Gemfile and Gemfile.lock I find the appropriate gems being bundled whether I use 2.0.0.beta.18 or 2.0.0.beta.20.

routes.rb maps /about to some specific action belonging to a specific controller. I also get the correct page when I visit the page in my browser; so I do not think that could be the issue. (Unfortunately I do not have the code with me right now and can't paste it here)

The following is the error which I cannot understand

```
arun@ubuntu-world:~/Project/Rails/rails3/sample_app$ rspec spec/
/home/arun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.0.0.beta.20, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.0.0.beta.18. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I do know what *bundle exec* is, let alone how to use it...

-- Arun

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove one of the gems using gem uninstall:

$ gem uninstall rspec-core -v 2.0.0.beta.20

You can also use gem list to view the which versions of the gems you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Rspec had been working fine for 11 chapters of Hartl's tutorial.  But somehow I messed with my gemfille and I started to get the same problem with rspec "stack levels too deep" and not being able to resolve by a 'bundle install'.  So I went wild and did a

```
windows> gem uninstall rspec rspec-rails rspec-expectations rspec-mock rspec-core
```

(All versions).  'gem list' showed they were indeed all gone.  Then I executed a

```
> bundle install
...
Using rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.22)
Using rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.22)
Using rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.22)
Using rspec (2.0.0.beta.22)
Using rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta.22)
...
```

Which is what is in my Gemfile.  However, a 'gem list -d rspec' still shows -no- rspec or rspec-xxx gems installed and rspec-core problems...

```
> rails g rspec:install       *#for good measure*
...
> rspec -v
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Could not 
find RubyGem rspec-core (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

But 'bundle list' says it is installed.  So how do I get rspec working again?

---

UPDATE

### I fixed the problem, but first my humblest apologies to **arun kumar** for camping on his question and coming in between it and an answer.  I thought my problem was similar and that my "answer" would be place at the end.

First of all, I had to do a

```
> gem install rspec -v 2.0.0.beta.22
> gem install rspec-rails -v 2.0.0.beta.22
```

instead of expecting bundler to do it.  bundler does not seem reliable here.  This got my calls to rspec working again, but I still had to deal with "stack levels too deep."  That was fixed by upgrading rspec and rspec-rails to 2.0.1 (from David Chelimski: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/282245).  Again changing my Gemfile and calling bundle-install didn't work.  I had to uninstall all five rspec-xxx gems like above and manually do

```
> gem install rspec -v 2.0.1
> gem install rspec-rails -v 2.0.1
```

maybe I didn't need to uninstall first, but I did.  The poster has likely already fixed his problem since it was so long ago, but here is my solution that may work for others -- recall I have Windows Vista64.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely has nothing to do with Windows or any environment you have there. I am experiencing the same thing with my Mac.

my `routes.rb` file (From the same tutorial) looks like this:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users

  match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try running

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```