# in 'require': no such file to load -- spec_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rspec

Came across this error when trying out the ruby on rails tutorial section with rspec on a windows platform using jruby 1.6:

```
c:\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038:in `require': no such file to load -- spec_helper
 (LoadError)
        from c:/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec    .rb:1:in `(root)'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063:in `load'
        from c:/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec
.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
        from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2458:in `collect'
        from c:/jruby-1.6.0.RC2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspe
c/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
        from c:/jruby-1.6.0.RC2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspe
c/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
        from c:/jruby-1.6.0.RC2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspe
c/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
        from c:/jruby-1.6.0.RC2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspe
c/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
        from c:/jruby-1.6.0.RC2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspe
c/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
        from org/jruby/RubyProc.java:268:in `call'
        from org/jruby/RubyProc.java:232:in `call'
```

Found the answer which appears missing from the tutorial:

c:\rails_projects\sample_app>rails generate rspec:install

Comment: Which Ruby on Rails tutorial?

Comment: @RyanBigg probably [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top)

Comment: It's not missing from the tutorial. The command in question appears in the introduction to Chapter 3. (Trust me, I know—I wrote it. :-)

Comment: 2 years later, just did chapter three. I can prove (to myself using the shell memory) that I actually entered the command. Still, the file did not exist until I did it again after reading this post. Thanks [Michael Hartl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/57750/mhartl), great tutorial.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After running

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

Place your `*_spec.rb` files under (in your example) `c:\rails_projects\sample_app\spec\model`.  Then specify relative path with require_relative

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'
```

Comment: don't use `require_relative` - it means as you move tests around, you'll have to keep updating the path. Just use `require 'spec_helper'`.

Comment: I hail from the C# camp, so my Ruby style is questionable at best.  This was a quick way to get things working. YMMV

Answer (score 12):

Run the following command

```
c:\rails_projects\sample_app>rails generate rspec:install
```

This will put the `spec_helper.rb` file in your `/spec` directory

Answer (score 4):

When you execute `'rails generate rspec:install'`, if you see `'Could not find generator rspec:install'` error message, add gem `'rspec-rails'` within `:developnent`, `:test` group in your project `Gemfile` as shown below.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

After this, execute `'bundle install'` and continue with `'rails generate rspec:install'`

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some use - in the event `rpsec` wasn't installed properly on a Win7 environment.

[rails3 rspec issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695504/rails3-rspec-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but for a different reason:

in my `spork.prefork` block within my `spec_helper.rb` file I had this line

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

but within one of the files that was being required above (`spec/support/some_helper_file.rb`) was a `require 'spec_helper'` call

removing this unneeded require solved the issue