# I keep getting an error in ruby : cannot load such file --spec_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I am supposed to type "rake" in the terminal form directory 00_hello and get an error like

```
(cannot load such file -- test-first-teaching/hello/hello (LoadError)), but instead I keep getting this error:

 (in /Users/deianp17/learn_ruby) /Users/deianp17/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)  from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'    from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `block in requires='    from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `each'  from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `requires='     from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'  from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `each'   from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'   from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'   from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:105:in `setup'     from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'    from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'    from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'     from /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
```

Now, I've tried a lot of things and looked around google/stackoverflow for answers but none work..or maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Maybe some additional context as to why you are supposed to type 'rake' would help help prospective respondents? Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150293/in-require-no-such-file-to-load-spec-helper

Comment: @Stewart_R yes I am following a ruby beginner guide: https://github.com/vikingeducation/learn_ruby

Comment: @JagjotSingh I have done that dozen of times but i still get the error, maybe I have to use that in a specific directory?

Comment: Did you run "bundle" in the previous directory?

Comment: @JagjotSingh how do I do that ? I just used bundle install, do I have to do it in a specific directory?

Comment: Yes, kindly clone the whole repository from Github, or you can simple download the zip. After cloning/downloading you need to go to that folder in your terminal and run "bundle install" there. Then run "cd 00_hello" and run "rake", then you would see your expected error.

Comment: @JagjotSingh I did this now: cd learn_ruby (the github rep)
bundle install
cd 00_hello
rake
but i get the same long error...

Comment: Try running "bundle exec rake"

Comment: @JagjotSingh ok i did that and get the same error, plus /Users/deianp17/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -I/Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib:/Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-support-3.1.2/lib /Users/deianp17/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec --pattern /Users/deianp17/learn_ruby/00_hello/\*_spec.rb -I/Users/deianp17/learn_ruby/00_hello -I/Users/deianp17/learn_ruby/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed

Comment: Great! This is the error you were looking for. Kindly recheck it from the file. I am getting the same error and it is the correct one. Now you can carry on with your tutorial. Cheers!

Comment: @JagjotSingh but i still get that old error.. am I supposed to get that every time ? And what do you mean by "recheck it from the file"? :D

Comment: The correct error is something like this: http://pastebin.com/4Mmru0ji

By recheck it from the file I mean read the file "hello_spec.rb" and you can continue the tutorial from after the error part.

Comment: @JagjotSingh the thing is, I don't have the same error as you. In the first line I get " cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)", not "/home/parry/Desktop/lol/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:116:in `require': cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)
"

Comment: @JagjotSingh also, i created the hello.rb file and saved it, but still I get the same old error

Comment: lol. Then I don't think we are on the same page. Can you kindly post the whole error on PasteBin?

Comment: @JagjotSingh http://pastebin.com/b1K73Q3u

Comment: As a last try you can run "rspec hello_spec.rb" in "00_hello" folder.

Comment: @JagjotSingh same error... could you please tell me the exact steps you took in getting the correct error..? Maybe I did something wrong in the beginning or when I installed rspec.

Comment: I cloned the repository. Ran "bundle install" in the root directory of the repository. CD'd to the "00_hello" folder and ran "rake".

Comment: @JagjotSingh what is the root directory?

Comment: Base directory i.e "learn_ruby"

Comment: @JagjotSingh  and how do you bundle install in there? just "cd learn_ruby" then "bundle install" ?

Comment: Yes, those are the exact steps.

Comment: @JagjotSingh damn..I dont get how we did the exact same steps and for me it doesnt work. Well thanks anyway for the help! :D

Comment: Sure no problem. As a precaution you can reinstall the gems. Run "gem pristine --all" and bundle in the base directory of the repository again and then try "rake" in "00_hello". If this doesn't work then, I don't know what will.

Comment: @JagjotSingh  Oh finally it works! I just needed the spec_helper file in the test folder. Not sure why I didn't have it in the first place, but whatever at least it works now.